# php echo method multiple array value by key

Tags: php

From a method I get a array value as return, the method is like this:

```
 $block->getQuantityValidators();
```

With print_r:

```
 Array ( [required-number] => 1 [validate-item-quantity] => Array ( [minAllowed] => 0.5 [maxAllowed] => 10000 ) )
```

How to echo only the value of "minAllowed"

Comment: `$arr = $block->getQuantityValidators();
echo $arr['validate-item-quantity']['minAllowed'];` try this

Comment: Read the accepted answer in the linked question, that will teach you something, unlike the answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$quantityValidators = $block->getQuantityValidators();
echo $quantityValidators['validate-item-quantity']['minAllowed'];
```